# Zen cart color picker

Tags: zen-cart

I can create a simple dropdown color picker with names of colors. using attribute options. But this is just a plain text. I just need a way to add color sample to the dropdown. How do I do this in zencart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes controller has an attributes image swatch that you can set to an image.